# How to prevent class from inheritance in c++?

Tags: c++

Can anyone tell me how to restrict inheritance in c++ with example?
is their any possibility of doing it by using private mode of inheritance?

Comment: make class final.yes you can simulate that

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a class to be [`final`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) and therefore no other classes can derive from it. You can also specify that individual functions are `final`.

Comment: only for c++11 i guess not for older versions

Comment: I think OP wants to know if it can be done without using the `final` keyword (since it is part of C++11)

Comment: @binaryBaBa What makes you think that they aren't using C++11? I don't see any mention of that in their question.

Comment: Exactly my point! C++11 is not mentioned. The tag simply says C++

Comment: @binaryBaBa It is the year 2015, I hope it is safe to assume that most people are using C++11 compilers, especially considering that C++14 has been finalized.

Comment: In programming, assumptions lead to doom!
I so wish all the corporate projects start using C++11.

Comment: Questions specifically about older versions of the language should be tagged c++98, not c++.